# What will happen if we short the secondary side of a transformer (whether step up or step down?) Why is the secondary side of a CT shorted?

Tags: transformer, current-transformer

I can't understand why it is dangerous to leave the secondary side of a current transformer open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you short a transformer secondary, then it is a zero ohm short circuit, an infinite load. At least for tranformers that are used to step voltage up or down that would not work because it would not be able to step voltage up or down, because a short circuit requires that output voltage is zero.

But CT are another thing. Sure they are basically just transformers, but used for measuring current. So the input is not voltage but current, so input voltage is almost zero. It will step down the current, which basically means it steps up voltage. But if you are using a CT, you are not interested in the voltage, but current. And you get secondary output current that is proportional to the input current.

Any load would result into less current, so best results are got by short circuiting the secondary to measure current in the primary.

And since a CT is a step-up for voltage, if the secondary is open, it might develop so large voltage across the output terminals, that it gets damaged or can be hazardous to people.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

When the secondary winding of a power or distribution transformer is short-circuited, protective devices, such as fuses / circuit breakers, would blow / trip to clear the fault.

The secondary short circuit current would reflect on the primary side as well.

Protective devices would be available in the primary as well as the secondary circuits, to render the system failsafe.

In a current transformer, however, the secondary current would be solely dependant on the primary current which, in turn, would be decided by the load.

When the secondary of a current transformer is kept short circuited, the short circuit current would be proportional to the primary current and decided by its turns ratio. An ammeter connected on the secondary side would also display the same current as its impedance would be low enough to present itself as a short-circuit.

The secondary of a current transformer is to be kept short-circuited, through a link or an ammeter, and never kept open. When the secondary of a current transformer is kept open, with the primary carrying it's rated current, the secondary voltage would rise high enough to arc across its terminals / damage its insulation / expose personnel to the dangers of electric shock.

Comment: If there is a reasonable chance that the secondary circuit could open, two diodes can be connected in parallel across the terminals to limit the voltage to a safe level. For convenience, a full wave rectifier can be used, with the DC side shorted. This will allow no more than about 2 volts peak when the load is disconnected.

Comment: @PStechPaul - Yes, two diodes back to back would protect against secondary open-circuit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a current transformer is to measure current impressed on its primary coil.  The short circuit in the secondary coil keeps the magnetization of the transformer core close to zero, making the primary coil behave mostly as a short circuit (or rather low resistance) as well.

If you open the secondary coil, what behaved as a short circuit in the original circuit suddenly becomes an inductivity that will strongly resist any change of current with a counteracting voltage.  This messes with the circuit on the primary side apart from potentially creating large voltages on the secondary side as well.

Depending on the involved frequencies, the core may not actually be designed for withstanding the much larger remagnetisation energies that result from the absence of the compensating secondary current: this may lead to an inductive oven effect overheating the magnetic core.